# Ударение в слове "пережил"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно ставить ударение в слове ***"пережил"*** в стихотворении Пушкина "Я пережил свои желанья"?

> Я ***пережил*** свои желанья,
>   Я разлюбил свои мечты;
>   Остались мне одни страданья,
>   Плоды сердечной пустоты.

Вроде  все говорят "переж**и**л" в нём и ритмически так лучше, хотя основная (неразговорная) норма сейчас "п**е**режил". Или тогда говорили преимущественно "переж**и**л"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Пережить (1)** - испытать, перенести, верны обе формы: **пережИл и пЕрежил.**

Кто-то шепчет, поет и любуется,
Я дыханье мое затаил, -
В этом блеске великое чуется,
Но великое я пережИл (А. Блок).

**Пережить (2)** - прожить дольше кого-то, рекомендуемая форма **пережИл**, ударение пЕрежил соответствует старой норме.

Гляжу ль на дуб уединенный,
Я мыслю: патриарх лесов
Переживет мой век забвенный,
Как пережИл он век отцов (А. Пушкин).

Comment: Спасибо, Вера! Выходит, в стихах всегда на последний слог ударение задумывают? Интересно, почему? Из-за ритма?

Comment: Ударение от размера зависит, это четырехстопный ямб: ударение необходимо ставить на  четный (второй по счету) слог.

Comment: Так в данном случае же он либо первый, либо третий, то есть нечётные. Не пойму что-то я. :(

Comment: Я пе/режИл /своИ/ желА/нья. При определении размера есть определенные особенности: 1) пропуски ударения: средняя длина слова в русском языке 3 слога, поэтому в  стихах, написанных ямбом, всегда возникают пропуски ударений; 2) добавление лишнего слога в конце.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.) Только я не понимаю всё равно, как обосновать, что не может быть здесь ударение на первый слог вместо последнего (он же тоже чётный). И потом, меня интересует, были ли стихи, в которых ударение именно "пЕрежил", и если не было, то почему.

Comment: А по-моему, в этом случае оба варианта подходят: Я пЕ/режил/своИ/желА/нья. Здесь пропуск ударения на второй стопе. А вообще стихотворный текст как бы накладывается на определенный ритмический рисунок.

Comment: Выходит, мы всё равно не поймём, как задумал Пушкин, как он это произносил?

Comment: Наверное, не поймем, машины времени у нас нет, а современники описаний на эту тему, скорее всего, не оставили.

Comment: :) Спасибо, Вера, за диалог!

Comment: Хорошо бы определить орфоэпическую норму того времени, она могла меняться. Для этого надо догадаться, какая новая форма старается вытеснить старую (при существовании двух форм в наше время). Возможно, старшей формой является "пЕрежил",

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется. Не помню, чтобы от кого-то слышал "пЕрежил", хоть в Грамоте оно и значится основным вариантом, а "пережИл" разговорным.

Comment: Вера, а где написано, что пережИл - соответствует старой норме. Т.е. устаревшая? На Грамоте эта норма дается с помет. разг.

Comment: У Резниченко (2010 год) пЕрежил (прожил дольше) - устар., а пЕрежил и пережИл (испытал) - верны обе нормы, причем именно в таком порядке, а в 2004 году - пЕрежил и пережИл (порядок другой).

Answer (score 4):

> Как правильно ставить ударение в слове "пережил" в стихотворении
>   Пушкина "Я пережил свои желанья"?

Нацкорпус рекомендует [такие](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&req=%DF%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%E6%E8%EB%20%F1%E2%EE%E8%20%E6%E5%EB%E0%ED%FC%FF%2C%20%DF%20%F0%E0%E7%EB%FE%E1%E8%EB%20%F1%E2%EE%E8%20%EC%E5%F7%F2%FB) ударенья:

> *Я **пѐрежѝл** своѝ жела̀нья,*
>
> *Я ра̀злюбѝл своѝ мечты̀;*
>
> *Оста̀лись мнѐ однѝ страда̀нья,*
>
> *Плоды̀ сердѐчной пу̀стоты̀.*

А в  "*Брожу ли я вдоль улиц шумных..."* -- [такие](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=poetic&sort=gr_tagging&ext=10&req=%C3%EB%FF%E6%F3%20%EB%FC%20%ED%E0%20%E4%F3%E1%20%F3%E5%E4%E8%ED%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9):

> *Гляжу̀ ль на ду̀б уѐдинѐнный,*
>
> *Я мы̀слю: па̀триа̀рх лесо̀в*
>
> *Перѐживѐт мой вѐк забвѐнный,*
>
> *Как **пѐрежѝл** он вѐк отцо̀в.*

Comment: Ну, это как раз ударения согласно размеру стихотворения. Как сказала Вера, это четырёхстопный ямб, и в нём ударения падают на каждый второй слог. Тут, видимо, это и отражено. Причём, как она написала, могут быть пропуски в ударениях, когда слова больше двух слогов. А у Вас на одном слове (и как раз на моём тоже) бывает по два ударения. Как вообще это понимать?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Как вообще это понимать?_ === Ну Вы же сами чуть выше дали этому объяснение: _"это четырёхстопный ямб, и в нём ударения падают на каждый второй слог"_.

Comment: Так я опять повторяю про пропуски. Цитирую Веру: "При определении размера есть определенные особенности: 1) пропуски ударения: средняя длина слова в русском языке 3 слога, поэтому в стихах, написанных ямбом, всегда возникают пропуски ударений; 2) добавление лишнего слога в конце".